# C# : Imported CSV File, Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, regex, list, csv, parsing

This code is an attempt to take two columns of numerical values from a CSV file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;

namespace PredominantValues
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<DataValues> values = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\yetih\\Desktop\\Firm_Inventory.csv")
                                           .Skip(1)
                                           .Select(v => DataValues.FromCSV(v))
                                           .ToList();

            int YEARHIGH    = 2050;
            int YEARLOW     = 1700;
            int PRICEHIGH   = 900000;
            int PRICELOW    = 5000;

            int maxYearBuilt = DataValues.GetMaxYearBuilt(values, YEARHIGH);
            int minYearBuilt = DataValues.GetMinYearBuilt(values, YEARLOW);
            int avgYearBuilt = Convert.ToInt32(values.Average(r => r.yearBuilt));

            int maxPrice = DataValues.GetMaxPrice(values, PRICEHIGH);
            int minPrice = DataValues.GetMinPrice(values, PRICELOW);
            int avgPrice = Convert.ToInt32(values.Average(r => r.price));

            Console.WriteLine("Low      - Year Built: " + maxYearBuilt);
            Console.WriteLine("High     - Year Built: " + minYearBuilt);
            Console.WriteLine("Average  - Year Built: " + avgYearBuilt);
            Console.WriteLine("High     - Price:      " + maxPrice);
            Console.WriteLine("Low      - Price:      " + minPrice);
            Console.WriteLine("Average  - Price:      " + avgPrice);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    public class DataValues
    {
        public int yearBuilt;
        public int price;

        public static DataValues FromCSV(string csvLine)
        {
            Regex CSVParser = new Regex(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");
            string[] values = CSVParser.Split(csvLine);
            DataValues dataValues = new DataValues();

            values[0] = values[0].Replace("," , "");

            Console.WriteLine(values[0]);
            Console.ReadLine();

            decimal test = decimal.Parse(values[0], NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol);

            Console.WriteLine(test);
            Console.WriteLine(values[1]);
            Console.ReadLine();

            dataValues.price = int.Parse(values[0], NumberStyles.Currency);
            dataValues.yearBuilt = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
            return dataValues;
        }

        public static int GetMaxYearBuilt(List<DataValues> list, int YEARHIGH)
        {
            int maxYearBuilt;
            int index;

            do
            {
                maxYearBuilt = list.Max(r => r.yearBuilt);
                if (maxYearBuilt >= YEARHIGH)
                {
                    index = list.FindIndex(a => a.yearBuilt == maxYearBuilt);
                    list.RemoveAt(index);
                }
            } while (maxYearBuilt >= YEARHIGH);

            return maxYearBuilt;
        }

        public static int GetMinYearBuilt(List<DataValues> list, int YEARLOW)
        {
            int minYearBuilt;
            int index;

            do
            {
                minYearBuilt = list.Min(r => r.yearBuilt);
                if (minYearBuilt <= YEARLOW)
                {
                    index = list.FindIndex(a => a.yearBuilt == minYearBuilt);
                    list.RemoveAt(index);
                }
            } while (minYearBuilt <= YEARLOW);

            return minYearBuilt;
        }

        public static int GetMaxPrice(List<DataValues> list, int PRICEHIGH)
        {
            int maxPrice;
            int index;

            do
            {
                maxPrice = list.Max(r => r.price);
                if (maxPrice >= PRICEHIGH)
                {
                    index = list.FindIndex(a => a.price == maxPrice);
                    list.RemoveAt(index);
                }
            } while (maxPrice >= PRICEHIGH);

            return maxPrice;
        }

        public static int GetMinPrice(List<DataValues> list, int PRICELOW)
        {
            int minPrice;
            int index;

            do
            {
                minPrice = list.Min(r => r.price);
                if (minPrice <= PRICELOW)
                {
                    index = list.FindIndex(a => a.price == minPrice);
                    list.RemoveAt(index);
                }
            } while (minPrice <= PRICELOW);

            return minPrice;
        }
    }
}
```

So far I am able to successfully import and split the file into a list only if I go into the CSV file and change the formatting on the first column from 'Currency' to 'General'. The two columns are 'Price' and 'Year Built'. If I keep the 'Currency' formatting, I get an exception: "Input string was not in a correct format".

I've tried parsing the string to remove the currency symbol, however I am met with the same result.

```
dataValues.price = int.Parse(values[0], NumberStyles.Currency);
```

I would like to store the numerical value in 'values[0]' in 'dataValues.price'

Comment: can you please provide value for currency string

Comment: What is the value in `values[0]`? Can you check please.

Comment: I'm curious about the "`RemoveAt()`" calls. If, say, a record has a year greater than YearMax, do you want to discount that from other checks, too?

Comment: Pranay - A value for the currency string would be $3,600.

Comment: CodingYoshi - After putting in the Regex, the value in values[0] was "$3600"

Comment: Joel - Yes, I do need that record to be removed from the subsequent checks to. I'm attempting to filter out all the values that exceed that range, but you've already provided an elegant solution below.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's clean up the `FromCSV()` method:

```
public class DataValues
{
    public int yearBuilt;
    public decimal price;

    private static Regex CSVParser = new Regex(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");

    public static DataValues FromCSV(string csvLine)
    {
        var result = new DataValues();

        string[] values = CSVParser.Split(csvLine);

        values[0] = values[0].Replace("," , "").Replace("$","");
        result.price = decimal.Parse(values[0]);
        result.yearBuilt = int.Parse(values[1]);

        return result;
    }
}
```

That done, it's not clear what you're trying to do. Reading the code, you have methods to find MAX and MIN values for both fields, but the process you use excludes values that outside of a range in such a way that sometimes impact other fields, and sometimes don't. I suspect you either want to exclude full records when any part of the record falls outside your range, or you only want to exclude fields that fall outside of the range and did not intend to cause side effects in your GetMax/Min() methods. Again, however, it's not clear in the question which you intend. I have code here for both.

First, if you want to exclude the entire record:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int YEARHIGH        = 2050;
    int YEARLOW         = 1700;
    decimal PRICEHIGH   = 900000m;
    decimal PRICELOW    = 5000m;

    var values = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\yetih\Desktop\Firm_Inventory.csv")
             .Skip(1)
             .Select(v => DataValues.FromCSV(v))
             .Where(r => r.yearBuilt > YEARLOW && r.yearBuilt < YEARHIGH && r.price > PRICELOW && r.price < PRICEHIGH)
             .ToList();

    int maxYearBuilt = values.Max(r => r.yearBuilt);
    int minYearBuilt = values.Min(r => r.yearBuilt);
    int avgYearBuilt = Convert.ToInt32(values.Average(r => r.yearBuilt));

    decimal maxPrice = values.Max(r => r.price)
    decimal minPrice = values.Min(r => r.price);
    decimal avgPrice = values.Average(r => r.price);

    Console.WriteLine("Low      - Year Built: {0}", maxYearBuilt);
    Console.WriteLine("High     - Year Built: {0}", minYearBuilt);
    Console.WriteLine("Average  - Year Built: {0}", avgYearBuilt);
    Console.WriteLine("High     - Price: {0,9:C}", maxPrice);
    Console.WriteLine("Low      - Price: {0,9:C}", minPrice);
    Console.WriteLine("Average  - Price: {0,9:C}", avgPrice);

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Second, if you only want to exclude for within each field:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int YEARHIGH        = 2050;
    int YEARLOW         = 1700;
    decimal PRICEHIGH   = 900000m;
    decimal PRICELOW    = 5000m;

    var values = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\yetih\Desktop\Firm_Inventory.csv")
             .Skip(1)
             .Select(v => DataValues.FromCSV(v))
             .ToList();

    int maxYearBuilt = values.Where(r => r.yearBuilt < YEARHIGH).Max(r => r.yearBuilt);
    int minYearBuilt = values.Where(r => r.yearBuilt > YEARLOW).Min(r => r.yearBuilt);
    int avgYearBuilt = Convert.ToInt32(values.Where(r => r.yearBuilt > YEARLOW && r.yearBuilt < YEARHIGH).Average(r => r.yearBuilt));

    decimal maxPrice = values.Where(r => r.price < PRICEHIGH).Max(r => r.price)
    decimal minPrice = values.Where(r => r.price > PRICELOW).Min(r => r.price);
    decimal avgPrice = values.Where(r => r.price > PRICELOW && r.price < PRICEHIGH).Average(r => r.price);

    Console.WriteLine("Low      - Year Built: {0}", maxYearBuilt);
    Console.WriteLine("High     - Year Built: {0}", minYearBuilt);
    Console.WriteLine("Average  - Year Built: {0}", avgYearBuilt);
    Console.WriteLine("High     - Price: {0,9:C}", maxPrice);
    Console.WriteLine("Low      - Price: {0,9:C}", minPrice);
    Console.WriteLine("Average  - Price: {0,9:C}", avgPrice);

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much for this response, I was unaware of the '.where' method. I did need to delete the entire record if one of the two values was outside a certain range.  I'm finding the high, low, and average values of the prices and year of construction for houses in a certain market area, I'm hoping to use this to reduce some of the leg work for residential appraisal work. I'm still getting the "Input string was not in a correct format" on the 'result.price = decimal.Parse(values[0]);' line though. I thought it might have been the formatting, but you've alleviated that.